# XMLHttpRequest TCP/IP Layer

Tags: xml

I have been researching, but could not find the information.

I was wondering which part of TCP/IP and OSI layer XMLHttpRequest belong to.

Answer (score 1):

Http is an application layer protocol so it belongs to application layer.